# Custom rendering in flutter | Shaders

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to **render some triangles with custom shaders** on Android and IOS using flutter?

The original problem is to draw strokes on canvas, but strokes should look like they are made with a realistic brush. I know how to do that using shaders but didn't find a way how to do that in flutter. Are there any solutions?

Right now I'm using the `CustomPainter` element and drawing regular strokes (`Canvas.drawPath`)

*P.S. also there is this issue in flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30763, but seems that it is not implemented yet*

Comment: *"Is there any way to render some triangles with custom shaders"* - see `Canvas.drawVertices`

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I've seen it, but how can I apply a custom shader on top of it?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Vertices/Vertices.html - you have `List<Color> colors`

Comment: @pskink but I do not need plain colors, or textures, I can do it with Canvas.drawPath then. I need to use GLSL shader on top of triangle. To be able to display something similar to realistic brush stroke (probably Perlin noise with some tweaks)

Comment: only color shaders are supported by `drawVertices`